# 100 people (or some multiple of 100) want to travel from San Diego to LA

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, recreational-mathematics

100 people (or some multiple of 100) want to travel from San Diego to LA. A trip by car takes C(x) = 100 + 0.6x minutes where x is the number of people who drive. The bus from San Diego to La takes C(x) = 120 + 0.2x minutes.

Suppose each person bases her decision to drive or take the bus to minimize her own commuting time. What will the total travel time be for all 100 people?

a) 13000 minutes

b) 12000 minutes

c) 11000 minutes

d) 10000 minutes

My try: if 100 people are driving on road, one car would take 160 minutes. then for 100 people, total time would be 16000 minutes. but the answer is 13000 minutes. somebody plz help.

Comment: what about all going by bus.

Comment: then it would be [120 + 0.2(1)] X 100 = 12020. but the answer is 13000

Comment: is not it $120+0.2*100 = 140$ for per person.

Comment: no only one person would drive the bus

Comment: Oh so rest of the 99 will be in the same bus. And for car the driver is the only passenger in the car.

Comment: ya and one way the answer can be 13000 when 2 people ride in one car. then total time: [100 + (.6)(50)] X 100 = 13000. but i dont know to arrive at the number: "2 people per car"

Comment: I have a feeling that you may not have right interpretation of problem. If only one person drive the bus and rest 99 are passengers in same bus then it would have given like that in the problem instead of showing variable x in $120 + 0.2x$. Anyhow I can not comment further as stack is giving warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this problem to be a little bit awkward and the only way I could find to reach the answer of 13.000 minutes is the following:

Suppose that $x$ people go by car and $y$ people go by bus. Individual travelling times are:

$$t_c=100+0.6x, \ t_b=120+0.2y$$

If you take into account that $x+y=100$:

$$t_c=100+0.6x, \ t_b=140-0.2x$$

Suppose that these times are different. In that case there will be some people who can claim that their travelling time is not minimal (because there are some people with shorter transfer times). The only way to avoid that situation is the case when:

$$t_c=t_b\implies x=50$$

This gives:

$$t_c=t_b=130$$

...and the total travelling time is $130\times100=13000$ minutes.